# Binding is not working

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Binding a textbox with value of Name2 doesn't work. Code is correct and works in a simple WPF application. Is there any other way to bind in devexpress?

[image]

```
<TextBox Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Name2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="429,27,159,0" AcceptsReturn="True">
```

```
public partial class EntitiesView : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name2;
    public string Name2
    {
        get { return _name2; }
        set
        {
            _name2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name2");
        }
    }

    public EntitiesView()
    {
        Name2 = "abcdefffffffffffff";
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in the Debug Output window of Visual Studio?

Comment: Everything looks allright to me. But what do you need the TextBox.BindingGroup for? Is it possible that the bindings are cleared somehow?

Comment: Hi @slfan! Actually i am using Devexpress MVVM, in which we can only pass or show values via binding.  That's why i need it. Code is working fine in wpf simple application but with this MVVM, there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to DevExpress directly. It rather relates to the common MVVM concepts. You said that you are using MVVM, but from your code I see that you've defined the Name2 property in the View and retargeted all the bindings within this View onto this View instance using the `DataContext = this;` line. I believe this is wrong way and you should learn more about the MVVM concepts before continue.

As far as I know  about the DevExpress MVVM framework, the binding, demonstrated in your code won't work at runtime, because the `DataContext` property of this View **will be assigned to corresponding ViewModel instance when application starts**. Thus the correct approach is:

1. Remove the `DataContext = this;` line
2. Define the Name2 property at the corresponding ViewModel level - all the bindings will work as expected.

If you are still want to use the wrong approach, but make it works, use the [relative binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) (but you should also remove the `DataContext = this;` line !!!):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

P.S. Please use the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/) if you find an issue in DevExpress products or run into a problem when using it.